# Cant apply voxel remesh in sculpt mode?

Tags: mesh, sculpting, remesh

Im having some trouble trying to apply a remesh. So I press R to bring up the interface to remesh but after that I dont  know what to press or how to apply it to my mesh. Pressing R or enter does nothing. If i go into the tool menu and manually press remesh then it is applied. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The hotkey is CTRL+R, isn't it?

Comment: Leander is right, in the latest versions the shortcuts are R to set the face size, then Ctrl R to apply the remesh

Comment: Yes, `Ctrl`+`R` is applying the remesh since 2.81 when remeshing was introduced. The change from `Shift`+`R` to simply `R` for adjusting the voxel size came with version 3.5